# NSNumberFormatter works with decimal separator but not with comma separator

Tags: ios, rounding, nsnumberformatter, decimal

I have been working on this for two days now. Time to consult stackoverflow.

I have an iOS user setting that allows selection of the decimal and grouping separators. It works perfectly when the separator is a decimal point, but when set to a decimal comma all the numerical entries are automatically rounded to the nearest whole number and any calculations lose precision.

The scheme is this:

```
//Use formatter to set decimal style for output
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:5];

//Set number format from preferences
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *numberFormat = [userDefaults stringForKey:kNumberFormat];
if([numberFormat isEqualToString:@"Decimal Point"])
    {
    [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
    }

    else
    {
    [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
    }

NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: result];
NSString* formattedResult = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
[display_ setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", formattedResult]];
[formatter release];
```

In decimal separator mode 5.5 + 5.5 = 11.0

But, in comma separator mode 5.5 is immediately truncated to 5.0 in the display and 5.5 + 5.5 = 10.

Not what I want!

Comment: didn't understand the comma separator mode. Where & How do you need that? Give a small example. We will fix this quick.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have found that the problem is caused by using a "," symbol in my number input string which is then converted to a double to be sent to an analyzer class for processing (its a type of calculator). I have a setting that allows a decimal separator choice between a point (".") or a comma (","). The problem occurs when the separator input button is set to ",". The analyzer won't accept the string as a double when sent with [[self analyzer_] setFirstOperand:[[display_ text] doubleValue]] if it has a "," in it. So I am trying to figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: And another thing. I know there are some localization methods that can set the decimal and grouping symbol separators, but I haven't figured out how to get them to work yet. I want to do this so it will look natural in places where numbers are formatted like 3.324,084 rather that 3,324.084. If I leave the separator button title as "." in comma mode it works except the user has to see the incorrect decimal format as it is entered until an operation button is pressed, then display immediately reformats it to use the comma form and calculations are completed correctly. Functional, but inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figured it out on my own. The number formatter was operating correctly. To get my analyzer class to work I had to send it a double that could not contain a comma decimal separator. But to get the display to look right in comma separator mode I had to send the string in the desired format to the display (e.g. 2.500,05), then reformat the string with a decimal points and commas as needed and then send that string to the analyzer as a double (e.g. 2,500.05). A little tricky since I am essentially swapping the decimal points and the commas. There is probably a slicker way to do it but this worked:

```
NSString *numberFormat = [userDefaults stringForKey:kNumberFormat];

//if the string has been entered using a decimal comma, do this
if([numberFormat isEqualToString:@"Decimal Comma"])
{

 NSString *displayString = [display_ text];
 NSString *newStringValue = [displayString 
           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"x"];
 newStringValue = [newStringValue 
           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@","];
 newStringValue = [newStringValue 
           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"x" withString:@"."];
 [display_ setText:displayString];
 [[self analyzer_] setFirstOperand:[newStringValue doubleValue]];
}

//there is no problem if the decimal separator is a decimal point, so 
//just send it as is
if([numberFormat isEqualToString:@"Decimal Point"])

{   
 [[self analyzer_] setOperand:[[display_ text] doubleValue]];   
}
```

Comment: Cool, this helped me with a problem to integrate an older `NumberFormatter` into a custom FormatStyle - in Swift ...